# How to decrypt a file and add it into a list of strings

Tags: java

At the line where I out.write(buffer, 0, rumRead), how can I add that to a defined list instead of writing to a file? I tried adding it to an Object list, but that doesn't work.
Here's my decrypt method:

```
public static void decrypt(String file) {
    try {
        File output = new File(file.replace(encryptedFileType, initialFileType));
        if (!(output.exists())) {
            output.createNewFile();
        }
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file.replace(initialFileType, encryptedFileType));
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(output);
        in = new CipherInputStream(in, dcipher);
        int numRead = 0;
        while ((numRead = in.read(buffer)) >= 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, numRead);
        }
        out.close();
        new File(file.replace(initialFileType, encryptedFileType)).delete();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to read the contents from the file as a String and add it to a String list, you can parse the buffer you just read as a String first and add it.

```
List<String> strList = new LinkedList<String>();
strList.add(new String(buffer, 0, numRead));
```

Be warned that this code reads a fixed length from the file as a String (not delimited by newlines). The fixed length is determined by the buffer size. Also consider if LinkedList data structure is appropriate for you

You can use BufferedReader to read newline delimited data from a file:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream("file.txt")));
List<String> strList = new LinkedList<String>();
String line = reader.readLine(); // will return null if reached end of stream
while(line != null) {
   strList.add(line); // add into string list
   line = reader.readLine(); // read next line
}
reader.close();
```

Comment: I tried that and It added all of the file contents to the list, but some lines were missing parts of it.

Comment: When I write it into a file it works perfectly but forming it into a new string doesn't completely work for some reason.

Comment: Keep in mind that code will only accept string with a fix length according to the buffer size. If you need to tokenize the input by whitespaces / newlines consider using Scanner / FileInputStream

Comment: Can you give me an example of that please for my method using scanner.